# Inconsistencies in SEDE URLs for meta sites

Tags: feature-request, bug, data-explorer

There is a weird inconsistency in the URL usage for meta sites inside the Data Explorer: For example, it's usually [academia](https://data.stackexchange.com/academia/queries) and [meta.academia](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.academia/queries), but it can sometimes be [arduino](https://data.stackexchange.com/arduino/queries) and [arduinome](https://data.stackexchange.com/arduinome/queries).

Why is this? The database names are probably already hardwired, but can there at least be a redirect from [meta.arduino](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.arduino/queries) to [arduinome](https://data.stackexchange.com/arduinome/queries)?

This would make it much easier to [link to other queries from inside the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/516017/the-current-sites-sede-database-handle-for-query-urls).

Comment: *grumbles* Yeah, that needs fixing

Comment: @Tim Any guesses as to how it happened?