# Alias "Post Link" in data.stackexchange.com generate invalid links for "Meta sites" of pt.stackoverflow and es.stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, per-site-meta

I create a query using `[Post Link]` and `[Comment Link]` and I noticed that the generated links are inverted for some sites, for example:

This https://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/775699/bug-in-links (query to pt.stackoverflow meta) generate links like this:

```
https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1
```

But the correct one is:

```
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1
```

Ths https://data.stackexchange.com/esme/query/775699/bug-in-links (query to es.stackoverflow meta) generate links like this:

```
https://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/146
```

But the correct one is:

```
https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146
```

others like Web Apps Meta and Game Dev Meta and Russian Stack Overflow are generating correctly:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.webapps/query/775699/bug-in-links
- https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.gamedev/query/775699/bug-in-links
- https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.russian/query/775699/bug-in-links

including the bug that occurred in *Arqade Meta* (mentioned in [Per-site metas are not linked properly from the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298517/198279)) has already been fixed, then it is a problem that only occurs in some cases, test arqade meta:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.gaming/query/775699/bug-in-links

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard is not dup, bug fixed to "Arcade Meta", see this: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.gaming/query/775699/bug-in-links work fine. The bug now is other sites.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard that's a bug specific to some multi-site queries, where links are generated by specific SQL statements. This bug is specific to Magic Links which are generated by SEDE's JavaScript libraries (IIRC).

Comment: If anything it might be related or a duplicate of this one https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281562/inconsistencies-in-sede-urls-for-meta-sites

Comment: @Glorfindel oh, OK, Close vote retracted, comment deleted.

Comment: @Glorfindel `[Comment Link]` the same problem occurs :/ (may occur with all "link aliases")

Comment: The [Sites](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/Migrations/010%20-%20Sites.table.sql) table inside the Data.stackexchange database needs to be [updated](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/SeedData/sites.sql) with a new value for the `url` column. [This update query at the end](http://data.stackexchange.com/esme/query/775708) is my best guess but it needs Nick to verify and execute as the production data might have more/other variations I didn't cater for.

Comment: @rene I'm going to test all the sites that I can and I'll confirm if there was any missing, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. well, that would be a waste of your time I think. If it is like this you'll have to check 160 meta sites. I'll try to nudge a dev in chat to have a look and ask if we can offer any help.

Comment: @rene you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. I went through and updated the sites that had URLs from before the `meta.` move.

The generated post links should now work for all sites.